# Troubles solving a graph problem

Tags: graph-theory

I'm having troubles finding a solution to this problem. Having these datas, I'm supposed to prove that a 1 graph is possible.
Here, $\Gamma^+(W)$ is the outdegree and $\Gamma^-(W)$ is the indegree of the W node.

$\Gamma^+(A) = 1$
$\Gamma^+(B) = 1$
$\Gamma^+(C) = 1$
$\Gamma^+(D) = 1$
$\Gamma^+(E) = 1$

$\Gamma^-(A) = 1$
$\Gamma^-(B) = 1$
$\Gamma^-(C) = 1$
$\Gamma^-(D) = 1$
$\Gamma^-(E) = 1$

I think there is a way to solve this problem with flows.
However, I can't find a good way to formalize it. Do you guys see any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Such a graph can be a union of cycles, therefore it must not be unique.  Maybe you want to require connectedness?

Comment: If bidirectional edges are disallowed, then it's unique (in this case cycles must have length $\geq 3$).

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones Even then I find $4!$ different (zthough isomorphic) graphs

Comment: Ah you're right; they are labelled digraphs.

Comment: My hunch was that they meant connected, and unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: I know there are many possible graphs, but I can't fidn a way to prove its existence other than trying to draw them (wich is not sufficient).